# what is the equation for the n derivative of ln(x)

Tags: calculus

$ y=ln(x) $  then  i must find  $ y^{(n)}  $ for $ n= Naturals $

i found that the general formula is

$ y^{(n)}= \frac{(n-1)!}{x^n} $ when n is an odd number

and

$ y^{(n)}= -\frac{(n-1)!}{x^n} $ when n is an even number

so i would like to make this into one equation but i can't think of any function that works as desired (changing from -1 to 1 in every natural) maybe floor ceiling of sine or cosine

Comment: I think you can combine these by doing $y^{(n)}=
(-(-1)^n(n-1)!)/x^n$, effectively writing a common $(-1)^n$ term by pulling out a $-1$.

Answer (score 3):

Throw in a $(-1)^n$, or $(-1)^{n+1}$, depending on the parity.

By the way, there's nothing wrong with having different forms for the even and odd natural numbers.

Comment: oohh i haven't though of that, then  it would be $ y^{(n)} = (-1)^n - \frac{(n-1)}{x^n} $